# tomee won't start from within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-tomee

I installed apache-tomee-plume-7.1.0 from https://tomee.apache.org/

I installed eclipse-jee from https://www.eclipse.org/ using the installation tool.

In eclipse I added a new tomcat v8.5 server since eclipse told me that was the installed version.

When starting the server from within eclipse, I get an error-message like this:

```
'Starting tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

In the console it says:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
... 6 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory$Unsafe
at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.LocalBeanProxyFactory.createProxy(LocalBeanProxyFactory.java:147)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.eagerInitOfLocalBeanProxies(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1563)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1309)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

There are some more errors but I think the NoClassDefFoundError might be the main problem... am I right?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using another version of tomee.
Switched to version: apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M3
This solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both version of TomEE, witch is Apache TomEE plume 8.0.0-M3 and Apache Tomee plume 7.1.0, it seems to run without error, both started from prompt and also from Eclipse plugin. However try to unpacked them in an directory whose name does not contain the space character.